# django-cities data import doesn't work

Tags: django, geodjango

I installed the django-cities plugin and set the following parameters in my settings.py:

```
CITIES_FILES = {
        'city': {
            'filename': 'DE.zip',
            'urls':     ['http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/'+'{filename}']
        },
    }

CITIES_LOCALES = ['de', 'und', 'LANGUAGES']

CITIES_POSTAL_CODES = ['DE']

CITIES_PLUGINS = [
    'cities.plugin.postal_code_ca.Plugin',
]
```

I also changed my db-engine to: `'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql'`. However, after running `manage.py cities --import=all` the db tables that were created for the cities-data are not populated with data, they are all empty, athough the command finished reporting success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It finally worked by adding the --force flag to the import command:

```
manage.py cities --force --import=all
```